# Existing Android project is not opening?

Tags: android, android-studio

hi my android project is opening but not in edit mode like it open directly with projects as shown in the image. Please help me to open my project again.

[image: Screenshot_1]

[image: Screenshot_2]

Comment: Have you tried by gradle sync

Comment: Gradle fails to sync!. post gradle error logs.

Comment: this error comes up Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: @SekharMadhiyazhagan I see only these folder in the project https://prnt.sc/q38sb6

Comment: @ShripadJadhav any help?

Comment: Do file -> sync project with gradle file & check whether it gets succeed or fails.

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh, paste the logcat here..

Comment: no logcat showing and the app is missing in the dropbox near a hammer i will send a image wait

Comment: @VijayaVarmaLanke https://prnt.sc/q39b9k

Comment: ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: @VijayaVarmaLanke any help?

Comment: @ShripadJadhav ANY HELP?

Comment: @Jaspreetsingh, anydesk?